# unix/shell/perl - how to export / bulk copy oracle table data to a flat file with fixed column position

Tags: oracle, perl, unix

I have an oracle table "test1":

```
Col1    Col2    Col3
Test    N   45677
Test    N   67987
Test    N   23981
```

I need to put this data into a flat file but at fixed positions with few extra unassigned spaces in the file. Such as:

```
Col1 = (Position 1 to 4)
Col2 = (Position 5 to 7) [data will be '  N' - N preceded by two spaces]
Col3 = (Position 13 to 22) [Data will be preceded by 5 zeros. ex- 0000045677]
```

The content in flat file should be like below:

```
Test  N     0000045677
Test  N     0000067987
Test  N     0000023981
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Show your code, what you've tried so far and what kind of problem you're facing. You must show some effort in order to be helped.

Comment: Look at oracle external tables, or use UTL_FILE package for file i/o.  There are plenty of examples of that available.

Answer (score 0):

1. spool the SELECT which meets your needs into a textfile ("dirty")
2. use DATA PUMP EXPORT on a view defined using the SELECT from "1."
   [Data Pump Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/dp_export.htm#i1006376)